# Мальвы-монашки

Tags: литература

Вопрос, конечно, больше литературный. Но поскольку есть такая метка - литература, я размещй его здесь. У Паустовского прочитала: "Красные и жёлтые мальвы-монашки покачивались за открытым окном". Откуда такая ассоциация - *мальвы-монашки*?

Answer (score 2):

Часто в литературе цветы ассоциируются с невинностью, нежностью, романтичностью...Такая ассоциация как бы подчеркивает внутренний мир героя...

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос вполне нормальный, даже хороший.

Этот образ не Паустовскому принадлежит. Мальва была излюбленным цветком в монастырских садах. Я думаю, если в корпусе поискать, можно найти не только тому подтверждения, но другие примеры использования самого эпитета.
Мне просто некогда очень сейчас, а то бы сам порылся.